# Automatic partition addition to hive metastore in a Presto setup

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, trino, hadoop-partitioning, hive-metastore

`Source: S3`
`Query Engine: Athena`
In our use case, several partitions (and hence, files) are added to S3 continuously and the partitions are made available immediately via [dynamic partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html). So the cost of adding partitions is not high.

Now, I am porting this to GCP `GCS and Presto with Hive metastore` (Trino distribution, to be exact). (I haven't tried [DataProc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) yet, both Presto and Hive metastore will be self managed)

I am looking for something close to `dynamic partition projection`, the way it happens in Athena. However, I haven't found anything automatic. It is either manually adding partitions or repairing the entire table via the procedure [system.sync_partition_metadata](https://trino.io/episodes/5.html)

Is there anything less expensive in Presto that'd help me in adding the partitions to the metastore without requiring a full scan?